# <apex:actionSupport> event not firing in <apex:selectRadio> group

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionsupport, outputpanel, selectradio

I have the below in my VF page.

There is an `<apex:selectRadio>` group with the options populated by a function in my controller, and below there is an `<apex:outputPanel>` which is rendered when the user chooses the value *Other* in the radio group.

```
<table border="" class="WizardTable" align="left" 
    style="width:35%; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1 1em;" >        
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div  class="MainPanelFont">
                Please select the format<br/> for the data request:
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="text-align:top; width:60%; padding-right: 3px; padding-left: 2px;" colspan="2">
            <div class="Mandatory">
                <apex:selectRadio styleClass="radioOpt" layout="pageDirection"
                    value="{!sObjectRFC.Mailshot_delivery_format__c}" 
                    id="outDR_delivery_format__c">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!MailshotFormatOptions}"/>    
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="otherDRDeliveryFormatPanel" status="vfStatus"/>
                </apex:selectRadio> 
            </div>
        </td>                                                        
    </tr>
    <apex:outputPanel id="otherDRDeliveryFormatPanel" rendered="{!sObjectRFC.Mailshot_delivery_format__c=='Other'}">
    <!--apex:variable value="a" var="a"
                   rendered="{!sObjectRFC.Mailshot_delivery_format__c=='Other'}"-->
        <tr> <!-- Other_data_delivery_format__c -->
            <td style="text-align:top; width:60%; padding-right: 3px; padding-left: 2px;" colspan="2"
                title="{!$ObjectType.Request_for_System_Change__c.fields.Other_data_delivery_format__c.inlineHelpText}">
                <span class="MainPanelFont">
                    <apex:outputLabel 
                        value="{!$ObjectType.Request_for_System_Change__c.fields.Other_data_delivery_format__c.Label}"/>
                </span>
            </td>                                                           
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Other_data_delivery_format__c -->
            <td style="text-align:top; width:60%; padding-right: 3px; padding-left: 2px;" colspan="2"
                title="{!$ObjectType.Request_for_System_Change__c.fields.Other_data_delivery_format__c.inlineHelpText}">
                <apex:inputTextArea styleclass="MainPanelFont"                          
                    value="{!$ObjectType.Request_for_System_Change__c.fields.Other_data_delivery_format__c.Label}"/>                                                                
            </td>                                                           
        </tr>                                                       
    </apex:outputPanel>
</table>
```

The problem is that when the user chooses *Other* in the radio options, the event `onchange` should fire, rerender the outputPanel `otherDRDeliveryFormatPanel` and show the inputTextArea to allow the user to enter details.

But the event must not be firing as when I choose *Other* in the radio options, nothing happens...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what are you rerendering here `PriorityPanelDR` don't found this.

Comment: You should better change the `rerender="PriorityPanelDR"` to `rerender="otherDRDeliveryFormatPanel"`

Comment: sorry guys, the actual code in my VF page does have that... but it won't render `otherDRDeliveryFormatPanel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the outputPanel is never rendered by default. That is it ID is not accessible by the actionSupport. To solve this you will need a "wrapper" outputPanel and rerender it.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="otherDRDeliveryFormatPanel" layout="none">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!sObjectRFC.Mailshot_delivery_format__c=='Other'}">
    ...
```